# Console.WriteLine(Enum.Value) gives different output in C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums

I am basically a C# guy, but writing VB.Net code these days.

Today I came across a very different behaviour of .Net

**C# Code**

```
enum Color
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
}

class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Color.Red);
    }
}
```

This prints `Red`

But when this code is written in VB.Net it prints `0`.

**VB.Net Code**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine(Color.Red)
    End Sub

End Module

Enum Color
    Red
    Green
    Blue
End Enum
```

Why so different?

Comment: You are using a number `Color.Red` when the `WriteLine` method is expecting a string. It would appear that the way C# handles this is to automatically call the `ToString` method which returns "Red", while VB converts the number 0 to a string "0". In both languages, you can ensure that what is written is "Red" by using `Color.Red.ToString()`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Color.Red.ToString())` will print the enum name, otherwise it prints the value.  As for "why", thats probably only answerable by someone from MS

Comment: @Blackwood `WriteLine` doesn't expect a string, there are many overloads. I'd rather say the two languages have different overload resolution rules. C# Picks `WriteLine(object)` while VB picks `WriteLine(int)`.

Comment: Looks like a compiler issue/feature. The compiled code becomes `Console.WriteLine(0)`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That seems to be a better explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# and VB.NET have different method overload resolution rules.

C# Picks `Console.WriteLine(Object)`, while VB.NET picks `Console.WriteLine(Int32)`. Let's see why it does so.

[VB.NET rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx):

> 1. **Accessibility.** It eliminates any overload with an access level that prevents the calling code from calling it.
> 2. **Number of Parameters.** It eliminates any overload that defines a different number of parameters than are supplied in the call.
> 3. **Parameter Data Types.** The compiler gives instance methods preference over extension methods. If any instance method is found that requires only widening conversions to match the procedure call, all extension methods are dropped and the compiler continues with only the instance method candidates. If no such instance method is found, it continues with both instance and extension methods.
>      In this step, it eliminates any overload for which the data types of the calling arguments cannot be converted to the parameter types defined in the overload.
> 4. **Narrowing Conversions.** It eliminates any overload that requires a narrowing conversion from the calling argument types to the defined parameter types. This is true whether the type checking switch (Option Strict Statement) is On or Off.
> 5. **Least Widening.** The compiler considers the remaining overloads in pairs. For each pair, it compares the data types of the defined parameters. If the types in one of the overloads all widen to the corresponding types in the other, the compiler eliminates the latter. ***That is, it retains the overload that requires the least amount of widening.***
> 6. **Single Candidate.** It continues considering overloads in pairs until only one overload remains, and it resolves the call to that overload. If the compiler cannot reduce the overloads to a single candidate, it generates an error.

There are a lot of overloads for [`WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx), some of them are discarded at step 3. We're basically left with the following possibilities: `Object` and the numeric types.

The 5th point is interesting here: *Least Widening*. So what do the [widening rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx) say?

> Any enumerated type (`Enum`) widens to its underlying integral type and any type to which the underlying type widens.
>
> Any type widens to `Object`

So, your `Color` enum first widens to `Int32` (its underlying data type) - and this is a 100% match for `Console.WriteLine(Int32)`. It would require *yet* another widening conversion to go from `Int32` to `Object`, but the rules above say to *retain the overload that requires the least amount of widening.*

---

As for C# (from the [C# 5 spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) at §7.5.3.2):

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions `{ E1, E2, ..., EN }` and two applicable function members `MP` and `MQ` with parameter types `{ P1, P2, ..., PN }` and `{ Q1, Q2, ..., QN }`, `MP` is defined to be a better function member than `MQ` if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from `EX` to `QX` is not better than the implicit conversion from `EX` to `PX`, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from `EX` to `PX` is better than the conversion from `EX` to `QX`.

Ok, now how is *better* defined (§7.5.3.4)?

> Given a conversion `C1` that converts from a type `S` to a type `T1`, and a conversion `C2` that converts from a type `S` to a type `T2`, `C1` is a better conversion than `C2` if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An identity conversion exists from `S` to `T1` but not from `S` to `T2`
> - `T1` is a better conversion target than `T2` (§7.5.3.5)

Let's see at §7.5.3.5:

> Given two different types `T1` and `T2`, `T1` is a better conversion target than `T2` if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from `T1` to `T2` exists, and no implicit conversion from `T2` to `T1` exists
> - `T1` is a signed integral type and `T2` is an unsigned integral type.

So, we're converting from `Color` to either `Object` or `Int32`. Which one is better according to these rules?

- There **is** an implicit conversion from `Color` to `Object`
- There is no implicit conversion from `Object` to `Color` (obviously)
- There is no implicit conversion from `Color` to `Int32` (these are explicit in C#)
- There is no implicit conversion from `Int32` to `Color` (except for `0`)

Spec §6.1:

> The following conversions are classified as implicit conversions:
>
> - Identity conversions
> - Implicit numeric conversions
> - Implicit enumeration conversions.
> - Implicit nullable conversions
> - Null literal conversions
> - Implicit reference conversions
> - Boxing conversions
> - Implicit dynamic conversions
> - Implicit constant expression conversions
> - User-defined implicit conversions
> - Anonymous function conversions
> - Method group conversions

*Implicit numeric conversions* make no mention of enum types, and *Implicit enumeration conversions* deal with the other way around:

> An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal `0` to be converted to any *enum-type* and to any *nullable-type* whose underlying type is an *enum-type*. In the latter case the conversion is evaluated by converting to the underlying *enum-type* and wrapping the result (§4.1.10).

Enums are handled by boxing conversions (§6.1.7):

> A boxing conversion permits a *value-type* to be implicitly converted to a reference type. A boxing conversion exists from any *non-nullable-value-type* to `object` and `dynamic`, to `System.ValueType` and to any *interface-type* implemented by the *non-nullable-value-type*. Furthermore an *enum-type* can be converted to the type `System.Enum`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no Console.WriteLine(Enum) overload so the compilers are forced to pick one of the other ones.  Overload resolution rules are very arcane and the VB.NET and C# rules are not the same, but both compilers are willing to pick one when there's an *implicit* conversion to the target argument type and pick the one that takes the least amount of work.

Which is where another rule applies, this kind of statement in VB.NET is perfectly valid:

```
   Dim example As Integer = Color.Red  '' Fine
```

But the C# compiler spits at:

```
   int example = Color.Red;            // CS0266
```

Insisting that you apply an (int) cast.  It only has an explicit conversion, not an implicit one like VB.NET.

So the C# compiler is going to ignore all the overloads that take an integral argument, none are candidates because only explicit conversions exist for them.  Except one, the Console.WriteLine(Object) overload.  There *is* an implicit conversion for that one, it takes a *boxing conversion*.

The VB.NET compiler sees it as well, but now the "better" conversion comes into play.  A boxing conversion is a very expensive conversion, converting to `Integer` is *very* cheap.  It requires no extra code.  So it likes that one better.

Workarounds are simple:

```
    System.Console.WriteLine(CObj(Color.Red))         '' or
    System.Console.WriteLine(Color.Red.ToString())
```